MariaDB's JSON_UNQUOTE doesn't work with emojis?
I'm storing JSON in a varchar(255) column.
The table has DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_uca1400_ai_ci.
This JSON may contain Unicode characters.
For example "" is encoded as "\\ud83d\\ude0a".
When I try to extract this value, JSON_UNQUOTE returns "?".
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE('"\\ud83d\\ude0a"');
?

How can I extract this value in SQL?

I do not see a problem: https://dbfiddle.uk/1XtlagfK What program/interface prints ?? What are charset/collation settings?

@Akina , I'm using MariaDB not MySQL

Thanks for the bug report - MDEV-35614

Thanks for accepting @danblack ! I came across this issue while contributing to Django. We need to use this function in JOINs to support a feature and MariaDB is the only backend that has this problem. Cheers!

This kind of reasoning and the impacts of a bug are good things to put into bug reports. Commented now.

Per comments, its a bug, MDEV-35614, it appears to be related to an internal representation at utf8mb3 where as smiley emoji's need a full utf8mb4.
